# Python: mupdf: invalid key in dict

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I am writing below code to remove annotations from a pdf file and then save it to new pdf.
However, I am getting **RuntimeError: invalid key in dict**.
Below is the Code:

```
import fitz
import re
doc = fitz.open("test.pdf")
for i in range(doc.pageCount):
    page = doc[i]
    for annot in page.annots():
        page.delete_annot(annot)
    doc.save('test1.pdf')
```

Error:
mupdf: invalid key in dict

RuntimeError: invalid key in dict

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots (thank you for posting the real code though)

Comment: do you mean to have your `doc.save()` inside tthe for loop?  did you mean to call `page.save()` if so?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `doc` type is dict

Your mistake is `page = doc[i]` because range return a number for examble:

```
for i in range(): # whatever:
```

the key (`i`) will be a number but dicts does not accept number it accept string.

***The Solution***

You need to convert dict data to index

```
import fitz
import re
doc = fitz.open("test.pdf")
for i in range(doc.pageCount):
    page = list(doc.values())[i]
    for annot in page.annots():
        page.delete_annot(annot)
    doc.save('test1.pdf')
```

Comment: thank you for your reply however, I now get "mupdf: cannot find startxref" and test1.pdf is not saved.

Comment: I just fixed the error you asked for :)